# Call toast notification in LWC from within fetch method

Tags: lightning-web-components, callout, toast

**EDIT**: 
I originally left out a part of my code which I thought was irrelevant to the question but on further investigation realized it was the source of the issue. Adding it in and then will also add the answer.

I was actually calling `handleReleaseHold()` instead of directly calling `doReleaseHoldRequest()` as I mentioned

---

I am trying to display a toast notification in Lightning Experience with the results of an API callout from my JS file. I'm not getting an error, but no toast is displaying. Makes me think that it’s an issue of event bubbling/listening from within the JS fetch method, but I haven’t been able to figure it out.

JS file:

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class HoldModal extends LightningElement {  
    @track accountId = '001P000001OUxqZIAT';
    @track msgToDisplay = 'default';
    
/// Added in this section - start
    handleReleaseHold(){
        this.doReleaseHoldRequest();
        this.doCloseModal();
    }

    doCloseModal() {
        const buttonPressed = "save";
        const closeModalEvent = new CustomEvent('modalClosed', { detail: buttonPressed });
        this.dispatchEvent(closeModalEvent);
    }
/// Added in this section - end

    doDisplayToastMsg(variant, title, message) {
        const toastEvt = new ShowToastEvent({
            variant: variant,
            title: title,
            message: message,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvt);
    }

    doReleaseHoldRequest(){
        const url = 'https://www.url.com';
        const params = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type" : "application/json",
              "Authorization" : "Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            body: '{"key": "value"}'
          };
        const thisReference = this;  // different this scope when called from within subfunctions, so setting variable here to use correct this
        fetch(url, params)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(function(data){
            if(data.message){
               // handle later
            }
            else if(data.errors){
                // 1. // console.log('thisReference.accountId: ' + thisReference.accountId);
                // 3. // thisReference.doDisplayToastMsg('error', 'within fetch', 'this is the error');
                console.log('thisReference.msgToDisplay - before: ' + thisReference.msgToDisplay);
                // 4. // thisReference.msgToDisplay = 'MESSAGE INSIDE FETCH';
                console.log('thisReference.msgToDisplay - after: ' + thisReference.msgToDisplay);
                // 4.a. // thisReference.doDisplayToastMsg('error','within fetch',thisReference.msgToDisplay);
                /* 5. const toastEvt = new ShowToastEvent({
                        variant: 'error',
                        title: 'title',
                        message: 'message',
                    });
                 thisReference.dispatchEvent(toastEvt);
                */
                
            }
        })
        .then(function(){
            // 6. //thisReference.doDisplayToastMsg('error','last then before catch' ,thisReference.msgToDisplay);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log('doReleaseHoldRequest error: ' + error);
        })
        // 2. // thisReference.doDisplayToastMsg('error','after fetch', 'this is the error');
        // 4.b. // thisReference.doDisplayToastMsg('error','after fetch',this.msgToDisplay);
    }
}
```

When I call `doReleaseHoldRequest()` I do get into the 
`else if(data.errors){` block fine which is where I'm trying to call the toast

**Things I’ve tried (numbers associated with commented out sections in above code):**

1. Confirmed that `thisReference.accountId` prints what I expect so seems that correct this context is being used
2. Confirmed that firing a toast message with my `doDisplayToastMsg()` helper method AFTER the `fetch()` method works **=> the toast displays correctly as expected**
3. Tried firing toast message with `doDisplayToastMsg()` helper method WITHIN the fetch method **=> no toast is displayed**
4. Tried populating `@track msgToDisplay` with the results from the fetch method and then calling the `doDisplayToastMsg()`

   a. right afterwards within the `fetch()` method **=> no toast is displayed**

   b. after the fetch method **=> toast is displayed but not with updated message content** (which makes sense, because the toast is probably being displayed before the fetch method is complete)
5. Tried creating and dispatching a toast event without using my helper method `doDisplayToastMsg()` (which really shouldn't make a difference, but just in case) **=> no difference, toast still did not display**
6. Added another `.then()` and called the `doDisplayToastMsg()` there with a reference to the message content variable **=> no toast is displayed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `doCloseModal()` function was closing the modal before the `doDisplayToastMsg()` function inside the `fetch()` was getting a chance to run. The `doDisplayToastMsg()` after the `fetch()` was displaying the toast correctly because it ran before the `fetch()` completed.

Solution was to move the `doCloseModal()` to inside the `fetch()`, after the `doDisplayToastMsg()` is called. Then the modal closes and also the toast displays as desired

Answer (score 2):

**added**

You get error message ONLY when `this` is undefined - not when this is re-scoped to different object. For your toast to work correctly `this` should refer to class `HoldModal` as toast should be invoked on instance of the class and not on any other element.

---

Although you are trying to save the scope of `this` by using **const thisReference = this;**, the scope of `this` has already changed because it has been invoked from ***catch*** block. The simplest way to fix the issue is using arrow function - does not have own scope so the scope of `this` is always intact.

```
fetch(url, params)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    if (data.message) {
        // handle later
    }
    else if (data.errors) {
        this.doDisplayToastMsg('error','within fetch',this.msgToDisplay);
    }
})
.then(() => {
    // logic
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('doReleaseHoldRequest error: ' + error);
})
```

Comment: That is helpful to know that the arrow function allows me to keep the ```this``` scope and that part works for me. However it doesn't seem like an issue with the scope because the ```console.log('thisReference.accountId: ' + thisReference.accountId);``` prints correctly. And when I switched it using the arrow function and then calling ```this``` directly, the toast still doesn't display

Comment: When I don't have the ```this``` scope correct, I get the following error message: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'doDisplayToastMsg' of undefined``` But when the scope is correct I don't get the error message but the toast still does not display

Comment: added in answer. Did you try arrow function? by removing all functions? it should definitely work with arrow function as there will be no confusion

Comment: (facepalm) It is working now. Turns out I had another piece of the code that was closing the modal before the fetch completed so by the time it got to the ```doDisplayToastMsg()``` the HoldModal component had been removed. It was working for the ```doDisplayToastMsg()``` called after the fetch function because that was getting called before the modal was being closed. Thanks for the pointer about the arrow function though - that part is cleaner!

Comment: WC. +1 good question though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to many then().then() promises, `this` scope has changed a lot.

Then when you call 
`this.dispatchEvent(toastEvt);` , `this` does not point to the component. A quick thing I can think of is to provide component reference in `doDisplayToastMsg`

```
doDisplayToastMsg(variant, title, message , componentThis) {
        const toastEvt = new ShowToastEvent({
            variant: variant,
            title: title,
            message: message,
        });
        componentThis.dispatchEvent(toastEvt);
    }
```

And then call it as

```
thisReference.doDisplayToastMsg('error','within fetch',thisReference.msgToDisplay,thisReference);
```

Another way would be to bind [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013674/the-correct-way-to-bind-object-to-promise-then-argument) to the promise or to dispatch event.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue with the ```this``` scope because I do get the reference to the ```console.log('thisReference.accountId: ' + thisReference.accountId);``` properly printing. I tried passing the scope into my doDisplayToastMsg but it didn't seem to help